# php getting error while sending email

Tags: php, email

i am trying to send email through php coding, but getting following error

```
Warning: require_once(Mail.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in  /home/madeingu/public_html/sendemail.php on line 5

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Mail.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/madeingu/public_html/sendemail.php on line 5
```

please check my code maybe you will get idea where i am doing wrong

```
<?php


require_once "Mail.php";


$name="lisa";
$mail_from="xx@xx.com";
$subject="testing";
$message="this is test email";



$header="me"; 
$to = "Shop <xx@xx.com>";

$from = "xx@xx.com";

$host = "mail.xxxxxxx.com";
$username = "xx@xx.com";
$password = "password";

$headers = array ('From' => $from,
'To' => $to,
'Subject' => $subject);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
array ('host' => $host,
 'auth' => true,
 'username' => $username,
 'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $message);


if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
 echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
  } else {
  //echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
 echo'<table width="800" border="0" align="center" >
  <td>';
  echo "We've recived your contact information, we will get back soon!";
echo'</td>
</table>';
  }
  ?>
```

please check above code its seem ok to me, as i check most of the codes online.

but maybe its related to php config, or php.ini changes..

please let me know in any case.

thanks

Comment: Hmm...well it would seem that require_once cannot open Mail.php for inclusion. Is that file in the directory the script is running in?

Comment: mail.php file is not there,so you are getting this error. From where you get this code?Copy mail.php file from that place also. :P by the way, you can try simple php mail, mail($to,$subject,$message);

Comment: You are using the PEAR mail package. Did you install that or have you confirmed that it is installed?

Answer (score 1):

**PHP cannot find your mail.php file !**

If your mail.php file is in the directory above the branch use it like

```
require_once("../mail.php");
```

If it is in the same directory inside a folder , use it like

```
require_once("mailer/mail.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'Mail.php' file doesn't exists in the same path as that of 'sendmail.php'..check the path of your mail.php